# Jmeter RegEx Extractor

Tags: regex, apache, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter's Regular Expression Extractor. For an HTTP Request, I am getting an HTML Response. I want to extract all the URL strings.

This is one example; the number after `tools` in the id part changes.

```
    li><a id="link_sub_sub_cat_tools14874187" 
href="/EN/shop/tools/tools.cat" 
class="cat-/tools/tools"><span>
 li><a id="link_sub_sub_cat_tools14874787" 
href="/EN/shop/tools/tools.cat" 
class="cat-/tools/tools"><span>
 li><a id="link_sub_sub_cat_tools14874287" 
href="/EN/shop/tools/tools.cat" 
class="cat-/tools/tools"><span>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I have created jMeter tutorials for the very subject.

http://my.kpoint.com/kapsule/gcc-e1bad3ad-61cf-4620-9733-e44a74af8a3e/t/jmeter-tutorial-regex-extractor-basics

http://my.kpoint.com/kapsule/gcc-1dadaeee-1572-4c83-81fc-8d401cade743/t/jmeter-tutorial-multivalue-regex

http://my.kpoint.com/kapsule/gcc-744b552e-c91e-4db2-9d39-37c6e66f22ac/t/jmeter-tutorial-json-array-extraction

Comment: Thanks I am going to check that one out.

Answer (score 0):

To extract url strings use regular expression- href="(.+?)"

To extract number after after tools in the id part use regular expression- id="link_sub_sub_cat_(.+?)"